# Singular matrix geometric sum

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, power-series

What is a fast way to calculate the sum

$M + M^2+M^3+M^4+\cdots+M^n$,

where $M$ is an $n \times n$ matrix whose cells are either $0$ or $1$?

I have researched an alternative way which makes use of the fact that $I+M+M^2+\cdots+M^n=(I-M)^{-1}(I-M^{n+1})$, however singular matrices are not welcome in this method plus it requires $M$'s eigenvalues to be less than $1$ in absolute value.

Is there a *smarter* way to calculate it than performing $M(I+M(I+M(I+M(\cdots(I +M (I)))))$, i.e. less computationally expensive? Alas, eigenvalues are not known beforehand.

Comment: What do you mean by *smarter*? Less computationally expensive? It also depends on the size of $M$. (Why do you need the condition on the eigenvalues for the geometric series approach? It works for any $M$ as long as $M-I$ is invertible. You can caluclate $M^{n+1}$ with siginficantly less than $n+1$ matrix multiplications.)

Comment: Since you seem to know the eigenvalues of $M$ you can compute its minimal polynomial $m(x)$, compute the remainder of division of $f(x)=x+\dots+x^n$ by $m$ and evaluate the result in $M$. (But if many eigenvalues occur it is not going to be much of a speed-up.)

Comment: @flawr Yes, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Myself Eigenvalues are not known beforehand, thanks for pointing this out I just amended the question.

Comment: If you know that $M$ is nilpotent ($M^k = 0$ for some $k$) and $k<n+1$ you know that $(I-M)$ is invertible and $M+M^2+\ldots+M^n = (I-M)^{-1}-I$.

Comment: @flawr I'm looking for the general case, additionally M is not nilpotent. (Good point!)

Answer (score 3):

Let $g_n(x) = x + x^2+x^3+x^4+\cdots+x^n$ and define $f_n(x) = 1+g_n(x)$. Then clearly, computing $f_n$ is just as hard as computing $g_n$.

Now observe that

$$f_{2n+1}(x) = 1+x+\dots+x^{2n+1}=(1+x)(1+x^2+\dots+x^{2n}) = (1+x)f_n(x^2), $$

to obtain the recursive algorithm given by:

$$ \begin{cases} f_{2n+1}(x) &=  (1+x)f_n(x^2) \\ f_{2n}(x) &= f_{2n-1}(x) + x^{2n} \\ f_1(x) &= 1+x \\ f_0(x)&=1. \end{cases} $$

I believe that this will require roughly $O(\log n)$ operations, if addition and multiplication require $O(1)$ operations. To evaluate it on a matrix argument, use [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to evaluate the $x^{2n}$.

Finally note that for fixed $n$, this expansion may be precomputed and possibly further optimized. The key observations used here were that
\begin{aligned} f_{nm}(x) &= \frac{x^{mn}-1}{x-1} = \frac{x^{mn}-1}{x^m-1}\frac{x^{m}-1}{x-1} = f_n(x^m) f_m(x) \\
 f_{a+b}(x) &= f_a(x) + x^{a+1} f_{b-1}(x), \end{aligned}
here applied with $m=2$ and $b=1$, although variants apply to compute $f_n$ for any (composite) number $n$.

Comment: In my calculations it takes $O(\log^2 n)$ under the assumption that addition and multiplication take $O(1)$ since matrix exponention takes longer than $O(1)$. (Nice solution, appears to be faster than mine.)

Comment: Any idea on whether using the last equation might make calculations faster?

Comment: @CássioJandirPagnoncelli Not in general but if you need to do this for a fixed N a large number of times, you can compute the most efficient way to do so, hard code it and use that. However, most likely it is not going to be worth the effort, see for instance [this](http://www.mathblog.dk/project-euler-122-efficient-exponentiation/) blogpost about the analogous [Euler project 122](https://projecteuler.net/problem=122) that is about finding the most efficient exponentiation method.

Comment: And I agree with the $O((\log n)^2)$ taken into account matrix-arguments and assuming addition and multiplication of scalars take $O(1)$ operations.

Comment: The idea is to use for large $n$, large for me means $\log_{10} n>5$.

Comment: That's quite large already that means more then $10^{10}$ entries... I added an identity $f_{a+b}$ at the bottom of my post that may also turn in handy.

Answer (score 0):

My purpose is the following. I'd like to use that we are in $\mathbb{F}_2$, so $1+x^2 = (1+x)^2$.

$$ 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots + x^n = (1+x)^2 + x(1+x)^2 + \dots = (1+x)^2(1+x+\dots x^{n-2})$$ so we can go on in this method and get $$ \sum_0^{n}x^k=(1+x)^{n}$$

Concluding you get that

$$ M\sum_0^{n-1}M^k=M(I+M)^{n-1}$$

If $M$ is diagonalizable that's just $0$.

Comment: I'm unable to see why use $\mathbb{F}_2$, could you enlight us through this path?

Comment: Just I was wrong, I've taken this assumption because you said that cells were 0,1. Scuse me.

Comment: @CássioJandirPagnoncelli Just to clarify: You consider $M\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ but the entries of $M$ have in your case basically only have values in $\{0,1\}$, correct?

Comment: @flawr Correct, $M \in \{ 0, 1 \}^{n \times n}$. These matrices often happen to be singular.

Comment: I just ran a small simulation on the probability of singularity of matrices in $\{0,1\}^{n\times n}$, this is the result: It seems the probability drops rapidly as $n$ gets big enough: http://i.stack.imgur.com/83U14.png

Comment: That is a neat discovery, seems to be Poisson distributed.